# how to send mail in yiimailer extension in view form

Tags: yii

how exactly do i use this in view? it works fine in controller but I would like to have it set up like a form. My main question is, how do I submit? how would i make $mail->send() as a button? Not quite understanding the example from it. It looks like the default contact form.

Sorry for the rudimentary question.

```
$mail = new YiiMailer();

    $name = Yii::app()->user->getName();
    $email = Yii::app()->user->getEmail();

    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->setTo('hi@email.com', 'hi');
    $mail->setTo(Yii::app()->params['adminWeb']);
    $mail->setSubject('Mail subject');
    **how to send?**
```

Comment: check the answer below and accept it if its resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to trigger the email.

```
if ($mail->send()) {
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
} else {
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','Error while sending email: '.$mail->getError());
}
```

Ref : http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/

Comment: that does not work. That will just automatically send. It's the same as in the controller.